# To prove or refute: $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f\left( \frac{n}{N} \right) = 1$ then $f \in R\left( \left[ 0, 1 \right] \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f : \left[ 0, 1 \right] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f\left( \frac{n}{N} \right) = 1.$$

Then, $f \in R\left( \left[ 0, 1 \right] \right)$ and $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = 1$.

---

Do I have to prove it of refute it?

Comment: Do you know the definition of Riemann integral?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $R([0,1])$. Is that Riemann integrable?

Comment: What definition of Riemann integrable function do you have? For the most common definition, your question is a direct consecuence.

Comment: Well, to be rigorous, the limit is only one particular way to approximate the integral. One should work the details of showing that, independently of the partition of $[0,1]$ (assuming $h\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$), and independently on the choice of the point where you evaluate $f$ in each interval, the limit converges to the same number. So there is some detail to work out...

Comment: Also, I am not sure the result is true. Take $f(x)=\chi_\mathbb{Q\cap [0,1]}$. The limit is 1, but it is not Riemann integrable...

Comment: Indeed the result is wrong.

Comment: @bartgol $f \in R\left( \left[ 0, 1 \right] \right)$ if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

Comment: @bartgol You're probably right, the exercise is to prove or refute, I just assume that was right. Can you explain your example. I'm not familiar with your notation.

Comment: I meant the function that is equal to 1 on all rational numbers and 0 on all irrationals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in the limit you only ever evaluate the function for rational values. Thus the values your function $f$ takes for irrationals are completely irrelevant to the limit.

Thus if you start with a function $f_0$ fulfilling the condition on the limit, every function that coincides with $f_0$ for the rationals will also have the property, but it could be completely arbitrarily on the irrationals.

With this in mind and recalling some examples of functions that are not Riemann integrable,  you should be able to give a counterexample.

Comment: Great explanation! thanks. I will try to come with a example...

Comment: How can I come up with a simple example?

Comment: What  an example of  a function that is not Riemann integrable do you know?

Comment: Many... by example $f(x):=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: I see. I did not really have this type of example in mind, as in my mind this function is Riemann integrable. It is just the integral diverges. Actually in the comments on your post a good example is given.